# Product of inequalities

Tags: inequality

Let $x \in [a,b]$ and $y \in [c,d] $ , where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$

Is the following statement true?

$\min \left (\left | x \right | \cdot  \left | y \right |  \right ) \leqslant \left | x \right | \cdot   \left | y \right | \leqslant \max \left (\left | x \right | \cdot \left | y \right |  \right )$
$ \Leftrightarrow  $
$ \left | a \right | \cdot  \left | c \right | \leqslant \left | x \right | \cdot   \left | y \right | \leqslant \left | b \right | \cdot \left | d \right | $

Does it have a name?

---

EDIT:
Modified set for a,b,c and d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, let $a=-1,b=0,c=0,d=1$

Edit for new question: No again, let $a=-2, b=-1, c=1, d=2$. The whole point is that its possible for $|ac|\ge |bd|$. Whereas $|xy|$ need not be equal.

Comment: Note for future viewers, do not downvote this,  it was answered before the question was editted to exclude 0

Comment: Is it still false if a,b,c and d cannot be zero?

Comment: @Cristi Updated the post

Comment: You might like to know that your question is true if $a,b,c,d\ge 0$. The reverse inequalities are true if $a,b,c,d\le 0$